# what is the best way to fetch a list of hashes with Redis in php

Tags: php, redis, pipeline

I am building a notification  system using Redis and predis (not mobile push notification, just a visual warning on a website).
For example, when user1 sends a message to user2, I create an entry in Redis.
On that type of event, I create a hash with all the information about the notification (date, content, sender...).
Then I add the hash key to a list that is specific to the user.

```
//creating the notification
notificationId = uniqid();
$this->redis->hmset($notificationId, array(
    "sender" => "sender's Name",
    "type" => "message",
    "user_id" => "recipient's id",
    "content" => "message content",
    "date" => new \Datetime()
    )
);
//adding the id of the notification in the user's message notifications list
$this->redis->lpush("messageList".$userId, $notificationId);
```

Then when I want to retrieve all the message notifications for the user I do :

```
$listName = "messageList:".$userId;
$arrNotifications = $this->redis->pipeline(function ($pipe) use ($listName) {

    foreach ($pipe->getClient()->lrange($listName, 0, -1) as $key => $id) {
        $arrNotif[] = $pipe->hgetall($id);
    }

});
```

I get all the desired results with this method, but if the message list contains a couple thousands entries, the operation takes 0.5 seconds. It looks kinda slow, Redis is well known for being super fast.
So I am wondering if I am doing things correctly.

Any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: 500 ms for say 2000 entries would be 0.25 ms per hgetall. Do you include data transfer in that?

What is the per ops time reported for hgetall if you run INFO commandstats?

Comment: In a simple test it takes my computer 50 ms for a user with a list of 4k notifications.

Comment: Why do you need to fetch 2000 notification together? I am sure you must not be showing all 2000 notification on a page. Why not fetch only the lets say first 50 records ???

Comment: @Jahaja the info command gave me :
    cmdstat_hgetall:calls=18311,usec=69041,usec_per_call=3.77

Comment: @Atul you are right I don't need the 2k notifications, but I am still wondering why it is slow

Answer (score 0):

You may be much more satisfied with performance if you use [phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis).

It's a php C extension you have to compile in your server.

I started with predis too, and was glad to benchmark [phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis) a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, I can't install anything on the server

Comment: Too bad. The difference is really notable.